# Async Servlet Feature of Servlet 3 -- how do i handle the time consuming task

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, asynchronous

I'm learning Servlet 3.0 Async Feature these days , it's main idea is to release the task which is binded to the Http Thread to another Thread so the Http Thread could back to the Http Thread pool (not blocking for the long task processing ), then ur Application could be more responsive . everything goes fine here .

---

i've found two way to handle the time consuming task

1. acontext.start()

   ```
     asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               serviceImpl(req, resp, adapter, context, isNotLeakScan);
           }
       });
   ```

   The Official doc says :
   `acontext.start(new Runnable() {...}) gets a new thread from the container.`
2. using a BlockingQueue , and then new a Tread to handle runnables in the queue.

   ```
   private static final BlockingQueue queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();


   thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   while (true) {
     try {
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       AsyncContext context;
       while ((context = queue.poll()) != null) {
         try {
           ServletResponse response = context.getResponse();
           response.setContentType("text/plain");
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.printf("Thread %s completed the task",  
           Thread.currentThread().getName());
           out.flush();
         } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
         } finally {
           context.complete();
         }
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       return;
     }
   }
   ```

   }

---

my question is :

- what is the difference between these two methods ?
- does the first one handled the Task management to the Tomcat container (suppose we've deployed the app on Tomcat)
- the second way just shows the way of handle task manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that:

(1) executes your slow task in servlet thread pool, resulting in servlet pool starvation (that's the case with Tomcat/Jetty at least). What that means is that if you replace `serviceImpl(req, resp, adapter, context, isNotLeakScan);` with `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);` and try to connect to Tomcat from your browser 200 times (200 is the default number of threads) - Tomcat is going to hang forever, not accepting any more HTTP connections.

(2) spawns a thread per task manually.

You normally don't want to manually spawn threads, poll the queue etc. Instead you would use Executors framework, it has queue implementation under the hood, and is based on internal thread pool.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/slowServlet"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class SlowServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        final AsyncContext acontext = request.startAsync();
        ServletContext appScope = request.getServletContext();
        ((Executor) appScope.getAttribute("executor")).execute(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000); // your slow running task
                acontext.getResponse().getWriter().print("Done");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And servlet context listener is (the size of thread pool is hardcoded here)

```
@WebListener
public class ExecutorListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("executor", executor);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // add executor fancy shutdown logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: from which point do u know the (1) execute task in "Servlet Thread Pool" ? and which way is better ?  tks for u reply ~~ :D

Comment: (1) [http://java.dzone.com/articles/limited-usefulness](http://java.dzone.com/articles/limited-usefulness) + I don't see a separate thread pool in Tomcat to run async tasks. Which way is better - mine, because it doesn't use servlet threads for slow running tasks and it doesn't reinvent blocking queues and thread pools

Comment: i've read this article , and that's why i dived into Servlet's Asynchronous stuff to find out why, i haven't found other evidence to show `AsyncContext.start()` is useless except this article , so it maybe wrong .